# How to mount an O-ring differential pressure sensor in a pipe

Tags: sensors, hydraulics

I am trying to figure out the best way to connect an [O-ring mounted differential pressure sensor](http://www.meas-spec.com/downloads/DP86.pdf) into 1/8" female NPT. Ideally would like to do it with something like aluminum tubing, but I'm not sure what the best adapters are. I don't have the ability to custom fabricate a solution so I need an off the shelf solution.

Comment: Where exactly are you mounting the device? When you say "female NPT" it sounds like you're talking about a fitting, but what sort?

Comment: @Air https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_pipe_thread

Answer (score 0):

That sensor is available in a package with NPT fittings from the manufacturer. Why not simply use one of those? You can find links to them here: http://www.meas-spec.com/product/pressure/DP86.aspx

If not one of those, there are countless other pressure transducers that do have NPT fittings. I'm sure you can find one using the search engine of your choice.

Unless you have a very good reason, there's no need to re-invent the wheel.